# Arabic characters are garbled when exported and viewed in Excel

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am trying to export my xpages to excel. It involves exporting arabic text and number to excel.

The problem is when I view the export column in excel (client name in arabic). the result is garbage.

My lotus database is configure to support english and arabic, encoding is utf-8

Any help is very much welcome.

Here is the code I am using.

```
var exCon = facesContext.getExternalContext();  
var writer = facesContext.getResponseWriter();
var response = exCon.getResponse();
docIDArray=sessionScope.selectedDocs;

//lets define domino classess
var myView:NotesView = database.getView(sessionScope.vname);
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=CustomerCare.xls");
writer.write("<table>");
writer.write("<thead><tr>");
writer.write("<td><b>Created</b></td>");    
writer.write("<td><b>Client Name</b></td>");
writer.write("<td><b>Daybreak ID</b></td>");
writer.write("<td><b>Request type</b></td>");
writer.write("<td><b>Status</b></td>");
writer.write("<td><b>Mobile #</b></td>");
writer.write("<td><b>Escalation</b></td>");
writer.write("<td><b>Request via</b></td>");
writer.write("<td><b>From</b></td>");
writer.write("<td><b>Updated by</b></td>");
writer.write("</tr></thead>");  
/**
debuggin purpose only
print(sessionScope.vname+'-viewname');
print(sessionScope.selectedDocs+' -selectedDocs');
print(sessionScope.vfilter+'-vfilter' );
print(sessionScope.catFilter+'-catFilter');
**/
//determine if user wants to export all or the individual documents 
//export all document in current display/view
if (docIDArray.length==0){
    //since some view are special evaluate them here
    switch(sessionScope.vname)
    {
        case "Status":
            var dc:NotesDocumentCollection=myView.getAllDocumentsByKey(sessionScope.vfilter);
            var doc:NotesDocument=dc.getFirstDocument();
            while (doc!= null){
                writer.write("<tr>");           
                writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueDateTimeArray("dxdateFiled").elementAt(0)+ "</td>");                  
                writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("cxClientName")+ "</td>");                 
                writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("cxDBID") + "</td>");          
                writer.write("<td>" + @Implode(doc.getItemValueString("cxStatus_1"),",") + "</td>");                                        
                //writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("cxStatus_1") + "</td>");
                writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("cxStatus1") + "</td>");                           
                writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("cxMobile") + "</td>");
                if(doc.getItemValue("escalationlevel").toString()=='[3.0]'){
                    writer.write("<td>" + '3' + "</td>");
                }else{
                    writer.write("<td>" + '-' + "</td>");
                }                           
                writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("cxRecRequestvia") + "</td>");
                writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("From")+ "</td>");
                writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("Closedby") + "</td>");                    
                writer.write("</tr>");
                doc=dc.getNextDocument(doc);
            }
            break;
        case "Categories":          
        case "callStatus":      
            var sString:String = sessionScope.catFilter;        
            var viewNav:NotesViewNavigator = myView.createViewNavFromCategory(sString);
            var viewEnt:NotesViewEntry = viewNav.getFirst(); 
            while (viewEnt!=null){  
                writer.write("<tr>");
                writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[2] + "</td>");
                writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[3] + "</td>");
                writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[5] + "</td>");                  
                writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[7].toString() + "</td>");
                writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[8] + "</td>");
                writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[9] + "</td>");
                if( viewEnt.getColumnValues()[6].toString()=='3'){
                    writer.write("<td>" + '3' + "</td>");
                }else{
                    writer.write("<td>" + '-' + "</td>");
                }       
                writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[10] + "</td>");
                writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[1] + "</td>");
                writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[11] + "</td>");
                writer.write("</tr>");
                viewEnt = viewNav.getNext(viewEnt);
            }
            break;               
        default:                
            var viewNav:NotesViewNavigator = myView.createViewNav();
            var viewEnt:NotesViewEntry = viewNav.getFirst();
            while (viewEnt!=null){  
                writer.write("<tr>");
                writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[2] + "</td>");
                writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[3] + "</td>");
                writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[5] + "</td>");                  
                writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[7].toString() + "</td>");
                writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[8] + "</td>");
                writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[9] + "</td>");
                if( viewEnt.getColumnValues()[6].toString()=='3'){
                    writer.write("<td>" + '3' + "</td>");
                }else{
                    writer.write("<td>" + '-' + "</td>");
                }       
                writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[10] + "</td>");
                writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[1] + "</td>");
                writer.write("<td>" + viewEnt.getColumnValues()[11] + "</td>");
                writer.write("</tr>");
                viewEnt = viewNav.getNext(viewEnt);
            }
    }
}else{
    var db:NotesDatabase = session.getCurrentDatabase();
    switch(sessionScope.vname)
    {
        case "Status":
            for(i=0;i < docIDArray.length;i++){
            var docId=docIDArray[i];
            var doc:NotesDocument=db.getDocumentByID(docId);
            var output:string = "";
            if(doc != null) {           
                writer.write("<tr>");                   
                writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueDateTimeArray("dxdateFiled").elementAt(0)+ "</td>");
                writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("cxClientName")+ "</td>");
                writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("cxDBID") + "</td>");                  
                writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("cxStatus_1") + "</td>");                  
                writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("cxStatus1") + "</td>");           
                writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("cxMobile") + "</td>");
                if(doc.getItemValue("escalationlevel").toString()=='[3.0]'){
                    writer.write("<td>" + '3' + "</td>");
                }else{
                    writer.write("<td>" + '-' + "</td>");
                }                           
                writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("cxRecRequestvia") + "</td>");         
                writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("cxUsername") + "</td>");
                writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("Closedby") + "</td>");
                writer.write("</tr>");
            } // end if
            }//end for
            break;
        default:
        for(i=0;i < docIDArray.length;i++){
            var docId=docIDArray[i];
            var doc:NotesDocument=db.getDocumentByID(docId);
            var output:string = "";
            if(doc != null) {
                writer.write("<tr>");                   
                writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueDateTimeArray("dxdateFiled").elementAt(0)+ "</td>");
                writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("cxClientName")+ "</td>");
                writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("cxDBID") + "</td>");                  
                writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("cxStatus_1") + "</td>");                  
                writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("cxStatus1") + "</td>");           
                writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("cxMobile") + "</td>");
                if(doc.getItemValue("escalationlevel").toString()=='[3.0]'){
                    writer.write("<td>" + '3' + "</td>");
                }else{
                    writer.write("<td>" + '-' + "</td>");
                }                           
                writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("cxRecRequestvia") + "</td>");         
                writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("cxUsername") + "</td>");
                writer.write("<td>" + doc.getItemValueString("Closedby") + "</td>");
                writer.write("</tr>");
            } // end if
        }//end for
    }
}
writer.write("</table>");
writer.endDocument();
facesContext.responseComplete();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at Apache POI. It's likely to have addressed the issue you're encountering and is also more widely used. The APIs for creating an Excel spreadsheet are pretty intuitive, especially if you've done similar things in LotusScript.

The approach you're using at the moment will throw security warnings to the user with more recent version of MS Office (it's generic to web development and MS Office, not specific to XPages). Apache POI will also mean you don't get those warnings.

Comment: HI Paul, Your opinion has overcome my problem. Thank you for the pointer. Now I am running POI .